# android UI react weird in gyroscope event

Tags: android, gyroscope

I have an app that used gyroscope to control the value of the padding. However it doesn't update the UI unless I'm touching or moving the device screen.

```
private void GyroFunction(SensorEvent event) {
    SensorManager
            .getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix,
            SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, mRotationMatrix);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);

    // I must put this line of code to make the UI thread update every time 
    tempTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(orientationVals[2]));

    imgv.setPadding((int) Math.round(orientationVals[0]),
            (int) Math.round(orientationVals[1]),
            (int) Math.round(orientationVals[0]),
            (int) Math.round(orientationVals[1]));
}
```

However when I added a temporary textView that update value according to gyro event, it works. But I don't think it's a solution as it will block the screen. Is there an other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does calling imgv.invalidate() after setting the padding work?

Comment: Thanks! It's working now awesome. Do you know why we need to invalidate it?

Comment: No... :/ but I guess it's one of those things that need refreshing